# Como puedo crear un archivo con datos adentro y si existe reemplazarlo con php

Tags: php, html, html5

Quiero que cuando llege una url :

> ?page=home&cambiar=user1

y que lo ponga en variable de $_GET['']

```
$Cambiar_recibido = $_GET['cambiar'];

//Imprimir esa varible 



 $usuario = $Cambiar_recibido;

//Crear el archivo y si ya existe uno igual que lo remplaze, por favor lo necesito o de que otra forma puedo hacerlo?
```

por lo que descubrí se crea con esto

```
$nuevoarchivo = fopen($titulo, "w+"); 
fwrite($nuevoarchivo,"texto qe contiene el nuevo archivo"); 
fclose($nuevoarchivo);  

pero no se como ponerlo en un directorio especifico;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mejor que filtras los request $_GET antes de ejecutar cualquier solicitud
y para tu problema puedes leer un poco visit [leer](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) pero aqui te dejo un simple ejemplo

```
$dir = "mydir";
$file = "myfile.php";
$contenido = "<?php // this is just a comment ?>";
$replazo = "<?php  echo 'DONE'; ?>";
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
       mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
       return file_put_contents($dir.'/'.$file, $contenido, 0);
    }else{

       $filecontent = file_get_contents($file);
       $pos = strpos($filecontent, '?>');
       $filecontent = substr($filecontent, 0, 
       $pos)."\r\n".$replazo."\r\n".substr($filecontent, $pos);
       file_put_contents($dir.'/'.$file, $filecontent);
       include($dir.'/'.$file);
}
```

ya se ha hecho la misma pregunta en [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146626/editing-a-php-file-with-another-php-file-using-fwrite?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Pero quiero crear contenido php dentro, las variables para guardar datos, pero sin comprobar que exista, solo que lo cree y ya